# SpringIntegration Mail: Failure while polling for email: Unrecognised SSL

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, spring-integration, imap

I have a very strange problem when polling for email using SpringIntegration and Imap.

everything works fine, but once in a while I have an error like if it cannot get connected to the mailbox, and as if it was not listening an SSL port.

Then after another while things are going ok. 
This is annoying if an email is received during this time, because one on my subprocess then fails.

Do you have any idea why I could suddenly get such an exception:

Everything goes good

```
2016-06-01 13:40:43,570 INFO [org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver] - <attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]>
2016-06-01 13:41:06,242 INFO [org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver] - <attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]>
2016-06-01 13:41:13,572 INFO [org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver] - <attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]>
2016-06-01 13:41:36,238 INFO [org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver] - <attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]>
```

Then

```
2016-06-01 13:41:43,569 INFO [org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver] - <attempting to receive mail from folder [INBOX]>
2016-06-01 13:42:06,228 ERROR [org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler] - <org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failure occurred while polling for mail; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?;
nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
at org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource.receive(MailReceivingMessageSource.java:117)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:144)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:192)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:55)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:149)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:298)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:292)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?;
nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:726)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.connectStoreIfNecessary(AbstractMailReceiver.java:227)
at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.openFolder(AbstractMailReceiver.java:238)
at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.receive(AbstractMailReceiver.java:260)
at org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource.receive(MailReceivingMessageSource.java:103)
... 19 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:671)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:504)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:543)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:348)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:236)
at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:117)
at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:121)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.newIMAPProtocol(IMAPStore.java:746)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:689)
... 26 more
```

>

Then it is good again

The configuration I used is described here: [SpringIntegration Mail Failed to create new store connection Unrecognised SSL message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37503821/springintegration-mail-failed-to-create-new-store-connection-unrecognised-ssl-me?noredirect=1#comment62517707_37503821)

I thought it was due to mail folder copy. But it happens even when reading/polling emails.

Any idea?

Thanks

Gilles

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that it's intermittent - perhaps the server is a cluster behind a load balancer an one instance is not configured for SSL. Maybe setting the `mail.debug` property to `true` will shed some light.

Comment: Or a badly configured corporate proxy.

Comment: Or a firewall or anti-virus failure.  It's a network, you should expect it to fail, sometimes for mysterious reasons.